# Telegram Bot API setChatPhoto()

Tags: curl, bots, telegram

So I already have a bot with implementations for several method, but with the setChatPhoto() I am just unable to get past the following error:

> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: photo should be uploaded as an InputFile"}

no matter how I format my input. Also searched the web and seems like other people seemed to have run into this problem but I were unsuccessful at finding a working solution.

My current code:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"chat_id":"-9999999" , "photo": {"type":"photo", "media":"file_id_from_previous_command"}}' \
  https://api.telegram.org/botBOTID:BOTTOKEN/setChatPhoto
```

Comment: Which type of chat is that chat-id for? Note these: 1.Photos can't be changed for private chats. 2.The bot must be an administrator in the chat for this to work and must have the appropriate admin rights. Returns True on success. 3. And In regular groups (non-supergroups), this method will only work if the ‘All Members Are Admins’ setting is off in the target group.

Comment: This chat ID is a placeholder. The chat of which the photo I’m trying to fulfills all these conditions. In fact, these are about the same conditions for changing a chat’s title - which I was successful at doing for the same chat [id]